# Magento 2: Custom block not working

Tags: magento2, blocks

**Route**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="testproduct" frontName="testproduct">
            <module name="Test_Configureproduct" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Block**

```
    <?php                                                         
    namespace Test\Configureproduct\Block\Index;                      
    class ConfigureProductCollection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template                                  
    {
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function sayHello()
    {
        return __('Hello World');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php                                                         
namespace Test\Configureproduct\Controller\Index;                 
class Configure extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action          
{
protected $_pageFactory;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
{
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    return $this->_pageFactory->create();
}}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Test\Configureproduct\Block\Index\ConfigureProductCollection" name="configure_product_view" template="Test_Configureproduct::configure_product.phtml" />
</referenceContainer></page>
```

**Template**

```
<?php


echo $block->sayHello();
```

Comment: have u  create module.xml and registration.php?

Comment: please provide code of router.xml

Comment: Everything above looks correct, update your xml code into frontename_controllername_action.xml

Comment: Yes, I have created.

Comment: Please check code of route @AmitBera

Comment: Is the layout file name `testproduct_index_index.xml`?

Comment: No, It is testproduct_index_configure.xml @AmitBera

Comment: URL: http://example.com/index.php/testproduct/index/configure IMG URL: https://ibb.co/xJQcd7y

Comment: Given answer try that and it will work @MasudShaikh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,
To register a module you need to add

> registration.php

```
<?php\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Test_Configureproduct',
__DIR__);
```

then create module.xml

> etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Test_Configureproduct" setup_version="1.0.0"/></config>
```

> view/frontend/layout/testproduct_index_configure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>                                            
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Test\Configureproduct\Block\Index\Configure" name="index.configure" template="Test_Configureproduct::index/configure.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>                                                         
</page>
```

> view/frontend/templates/index/configure.phtml

```
<?php echo "hello world"; ?>
```

> etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>                                          
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route frontName="testproduct" id="testproduct">
        <module name="Test_Configureproduct"/>
    </route>
</router></config>
```

> Controller/Index/Configure.php

```
<?php                                                         
namespace Test\Configureproduct\Controller\Index;                 
class Configure extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{

protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * Execute view action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
 */
public function execute()
{
    return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
}}
```

> Block/Index/Configure.php

```
<?php                                                         
namespace Test\Configureproduct\Block\Index;                      
class Configure extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context  $context
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have checked not created the block.

Comment: Is that hello world displayed in front or not?

Comment: Not display hello world in front.

Comment: Check whether your module is installed or not? in app/etc/config.php

Comment: Module is installed and URl also working fine URL: example.com/index.php/testproduct/index/configure IMG URL: ibb.co/xJQcd7y

Comment: Please check image link

Comment: Previous code also give me the same result. But custom block is not working.

Comment: Updated the answer and try it out and it's working for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90301/discussion-between-g-prathap-and-masud-shaikh).

Comment: Not working on my local server

Comment: shaikhmasud147@gmail.com

Answer (score -2):

> Change execute method of controller

```
public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
```