# Magento 2 how to get product ID Price

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-prices

How to get product ID Price, if I have some many product,

I want like this get the product ID Price

`<?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product(ID)) ?>`

for example: i have two products ID is 1, 2. and i want get this two products price to showing in my custom page. just want to get the product price.

How can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: update,please see the post again, i want get Every product price, like product (id) , want to showing product price for my custom page.@PrathapGunasekaran

Comment: Try my answer and it will work

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Add the below code in you block

```
<?php                                                                 
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block;                                          
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;                              
class GetPricce extends Template                                              
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepo
    ) {     
        $this->productRepo = $productRepo;
    }

    public function getProductPrice($productId = '')
    {
        $product = $this->productRepo->getById($productId);
        return $product->getPrice();
    }
}
```

The above should be in your block and your phtml you can call like

```
<?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product(ID)) ?>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: ModuleName is my theme name or Magento_Theme? if my custom file in `app/design/frontend/Abc/Magento_Theme/templates` , please help, thank you

Comment: Block should go under custom module, and you should add the phtml to respective block through xml. Please let me know it you need any more information

Comment: My file full path in `app/design/frontend/Abc/Magento_Theme/templates/demo.phtml`, so i change `[ModuleName` to `Magento_Theme`? , can you help? thank you please

Comment: The module in `app/code/123/Abc`

Comment: See you should create a module first then you have to add a block and map to your phtml and hoping that's where you get your product ids.
Thanks

Comment: Try this to create a module https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263597/magento-2-custom-block-not-working/263604#263604

Comment: Yes, in my xml `<referenceContainer name="123"><block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="123" template="Magento_Theme::demo.phtml" after="cms_page" </referenceContainer>` , my cms page can get it to showing , but want demo.phtml can display product price from myself. please help,thank you

Comment: Replace this "Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" with this "Vendor\ModuleName\Block\GetPrice"

Comment: But the "ModuleName" dont need edit? thank you

Comment: not work,@BareFeet is my meaning, but just can showing Default currency and too much long code for one product price. i want more short. can you help to see?thank you!

Comment: This is an shortest way and you question isn't have all your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Using object manager (not recommended):

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(product_id_here);
$productPriceById = $productCollection->getPrice();
echo $productPriceById;
?>
```

Comment: Hi, i want get Every product price, like $_product(id:1), $_product(id:2)

Comment: want to showing product price for my custom page.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, you question was a bit difficult to understand :/

Comment: for exsample: i have two products ID is 1, 2. and i want get this two products price to showing in my custom page. just want to get the this product price. thank you

Comment: You want specific product price in the sense get that by id

Comment: No, just get the product price to my custom page. Custom to my display. Look like i just display ID(1) and ID(3) product price, but not display ID(2).

Comment: I think @PrathapGunasekaran gave you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Can control by myself, like i just write <?php echo "Hello world!"; ?> in my custom page will showing Hello world!. i want the product price from my Different products

Comment: I'm giving up... Not sure what your requirement is anymore :D See my edit, that should display the product price. All you have to do is, add the product ID in the correct place.

Comment: in my xml `<referenceContainer name="123"><block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="123" template="Magento_Theme::demo.phtml" after="cms_page" </referenceContainer>` , my cms page can get it to show , but want demo.phtml can display product price from myself.

Comment: i tested your post is work, but just one price, if i have too many product how can i change the id and make it short code? thank you