# The form from the custom module is not displayed

Tags: magento2

the form cannot be displayed, the page opens, but is empty.

> /view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

```
<form class="form feedback"
      action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormAction()) ?>"
      id="feedback-form"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Write Us')) ?></span></legend><br />
        <div class="field note no-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Jot us a note and we’ll get back to you as quickly as possible.')) ?></div>
        <div class="field name required">
            <label class="label" for="name"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Name')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="name" id="name" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Name')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('RonisBt\Feedback\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('name') ?: $this->helper('RonisBt\Feedback\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field email required">
            <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="email" id="email" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('RonisBt\Feedback\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('email') ?: $this->helper('RonisBt\Feedback\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field subject required">
            <span class="label-subject">Subject:</span>
            <select class="ronis_select required-entry select" id="select_feedback" name="subject">
            <option value="clothing">Clothing</option>
            <option value="delivery">Delivery</option>
            <option value="purchase returns">Purchase returns</option>
            <option value="other" id="admOther">Other</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="field telephone">
            <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone Number')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone Number')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('RonisBt\Feedback\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('telephone')) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field comment required">
            <label class="label" for="comment"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('What’s on your mind?')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('What’s on your mind?')) ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}"><?= $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('RonisBt\Feedback\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('comment')) ?></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info') ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Submit')) ?>" class="action submit primary">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

> /view/frontend/layout/feedback_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Feedback</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="RonisBt\Feedback\Block\FeedbackForm" name="feedbackForm" template="RonisBt_Feedback::form.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" label="Form Additional Info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> /Block/FeedbackForm.php

```
<?php
namespace RonisBt\Feedback\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Main contact form block
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class FeedbackForm extends Template
{
    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns action url for contact form
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('feedback/index/post', ['_secure' => true]);
    }
}
```

> etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Url\SecurityInfo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="secureUrlList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="feedback" xsi:type="string">/feedback/</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> page_types.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page_types xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_types.xsd">
    <type id="feedback_index_index" label="Feedback Form"/>
</page_types>
```

> routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="feedback" frontName="feedback">
            <module name="RonisBt_Feedback" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> /controller/index.php

```
<?php
namespace RonisBt\Feedback\Controller;

use RonisBt\Feedback\Model\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;

/**
 * Feedback module base controller
 */
abstract class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Recipient email config path
     */
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT = ConfigInterface::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT;

    /**
     * Sender email config path
     */
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER = ConfigInterface::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER;

    /**
     * Email template config path
     */
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = ConfigInterface::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE;

    /**
     * Enabled config path
     */
    const XML_PATH_ENABLED = ConfigInterface::XML_PATH_ENABLED;

    /**
     * @var ConfigInterface
     */
    private $feedbackConfig;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param ConfigInterface $feedbackConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ConfigInterface $feedbackConfig
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->feedbackConfig = $feedbackConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Dispatch request
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        if (!$this->feedbackConfig->isEnabled()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Page not found.'));
        }
        return parent::dispatch($request);
    }
}
```

> /Controller/Index/index.php

```
<?php
namespace RonisBt\Feedback\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \RonisBt\Feedback\Controller\Index implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * Show feedback page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
    }
}
```

> Controller/Index/Post.php

```
<?php
namespace RonisBt\Feedback\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;
use RonisBt\Feedback\Model\ConfigInterface;
use RonisBt\Feedback\Model\MailInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Post extends \RonisBt\Feedback\Controller\Index implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    private $context;

    /**
     * @var MailInterface
     */
    private $mail;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param ConfigInterface $feedbackConfig
     * @param MailInterface $mail
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ConfigInterface $feedbackConfig,
        MailInterface $mail,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        LoggerInterface $logger = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $feedbackConfig);
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->mail = $mail;
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->logger = $logger ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(LoggerInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * Post user question
     *
     * @return Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
        }
        try {
            $this->sendEmail($this->validatedParams());
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
            );
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('feedback');
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            $this->dataPersistor->set('feedback', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('An error occurred while processing your form. Please try again later.')
            );
            $this->dataPersistor->set('feedback', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
        }
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('feedback/index');
    }

    /**
     * @param array $post Post data from feedback form
     * @return void
     */
    private function sendEmail($post)
    {
        $this->mail->send(
            $post['email'],
            ['data' => new DataObject($post)]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    private function validatedParams()
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if (trim($request->getParam('name')) === '') {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Enter the Name and try again.'));
        }
        if (trim($request->getParam('comment')) === '') {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Enter the comment and try again.'));
        }
        if (false === \strpos($request->getParam('email'), '@')) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('The email address is invalid. Verify the email address and try again.'));
        }

        return $request->getParams();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks everything is right give us your controller

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263597/magento-2-custom-block-not-working/263604#263604

Comment: Changed the question, added controllers

Answer (score 0):

Check your folder spelling. **block** should be **Block**. Block file dir:

> app/code/RonisBt/Feedback/Block/FeedbackForm.php

All other file location:

> app/code/RonisBt/Feedback/Controller/Index/Index.php
> app/code/RonisBt/Feedback/etc/frontend/routes.xml
>
> app/code/RonisBt/Feedback/etc/di.xml
>
> app/code/RonisBt/Feedback/view/frontend/layout/feedback_index_index.xml
> app/code/RonisBt/Feedback/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml
> app/code/RonisBt/Feedback/etc/module.xml
> app/code/RonisBt/Feedback/registration.php
> app/code/RonisBt/Feedback/Helper/Data.php

Comment: Checked, all directories and files are named correctly.

Comment: I copy all file from your post working fine here. Can you see any error log?

Comment: What is that :D

Comment: Oh sorry)so in the logs for today there are no errors

Comment: When I do var_dump($context);die; in /Block/FeedbackForm.php in the method __construct then I have to get an array, for page /feedback/ and I don’t print anything